# TCP socket buffer sizes should also be an even multiple of the MSS for the connection

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, buffer

There is a paragraph in "unix network programming", says:

> To avoid wasting potential buffer space, the TCP socket buffer sizes
>   should also be an even multiple of the MSS for the connection. Some
>   implementations handle this detail for the application, rounding up
>   the socket buffer size after the connection is established (p. 902 of
>   TCPv2). This is another reason to set these two socket options before
>   establishing a connection. For example, using the default 4.4BSD size
>   of 8,192 and assuming an Ethernet with an MSS of 1,460, both socket
>   buffers are rounded up to 8,760 (6 x 1,460) when the connection is
>   established. This is not a crucial requirement; the additional space
>   in the socket buffer above the multiple of the MSS is simply unused.

I can not imagine how "**wasting** potential buffer space" happens. Why **waste**?
What will happen if the buffer size is not an even multiple of the MSS?
Can anybody help me and explain it? Or can anybody offer an example or scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most packets have the maximum segment size (MSS).  For that reason, the buffer will tend to accumulate data in multiples of the MSS.  If the remaining buffer space is less than the MSS, which will happen when the buffer is not an integral multiple of the MSS, there will not be space for another full size packet.  In this situation, the algorithm for avoidance of the Silly Window Syndrome has the receiver advertise a 0 window, shutting down data receipt until enough space is again available to accommodate the MSS, and resulting in the extra buffer space being "wasted".

Note that depending on the pattern of consumption of the data by the recipient and production of the data by the sender, the extra buffer space may not be completely wasted.  For example, the recipient may consume the data gradually, in which case the extra space will result in enough room to accommodate the MSS sooner than would happen with a buffer that was only the exact integral multiple of the MSS.  Similarly, if the sender produces data gradually, smaller packets may be sent, resulting in the data not being received in multiples of the MSS in the first place.  The concern is basically a minor efficiency concern in situations where the network is limiting to the data transfer rate.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the passage is nonsense.

1. If the size is 8760, there is no excess to be wasted. 8760 *is* a multiple of the MSS.
2. The final sentence appears to be talking about the case where it *isn't* rounded to a multiple of the MSS.
3. However, this 'excess' assumes that all received segments are MSS-sized, of which there is no guarantee.
4. It also assumes that the application *reads* in MSS-sized chunks, which is highly unusual.

So the stuff about wasted space is all completely incorrect. Ignore it.

**EDIT** This paragraph appears in W. R. Stevens, Bill Fenner, Andrew M. Rudolph, *Unix Network Programming,* volume I, 3rd edition, Addison Wesley 2004, section 7.5, p208. In fairness to the late and esteemed WRS it should be noted that the material about wasted space does not appear in the second edition (1998), the last one he wrote *solo.* It is to be presumed that it was added by the new co-authors for the third edition.

Stevens originally only said the part starting 'TCP socket buffer sizes should also be an even multiple of the MSS for the connection', and ending 'when the connection is established', without saying anything about wasted space, or why. Clearly it is for efficiency *on the wire.* As it happens, this is also usually incorrect, as it assumes that the application reads in MSS-sized chunks: the moment it doesn't do that, the rationale disappears out the window.

Comment: *"... the passage is nonsense..."* - I seriously doubt Stevens provided nonsensical information. I'm hazarding a guess, but it was probably very relevant when the book was current given how often Stevens cited source code. It may be no longer relevant today but I would hardly call it nonsense.

Comment: Thanks. I stopped reading after the first sentence. It seriously diminishes the answer. Maybe it would be a good idea to update the answer and fold the edits into a single coherent answer.

Comment: Thanks. Well, if you want people to take the answer seriously then it may be wise to provide a coherent answer. You are the only person I know who has criticized Stevens as being non-sensical. Some folks are going to stop reading at that point, like me.

Comment: If you want people to take the answer seriously then you should be careful of the claims you make.

Comment: @jww The claims I made are accurate. You simply haven't read them accurately. You've admitted it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

According to the quote, if you ask for a buffer of size 8192, the allocated buffer will actually be 8760 bytes. This means more memory is allocated than your application intends to use. The memory is wasted, in the sense that it is reserved for the buffer but won't actually get used for anything.

For the same amount of used memory your application could actually use a larger buffer of 8760 bytes. Using the smaller buffer of 8192 bytes doesn't actually save any memory, because internally there will be 8760 bytes allocated anyway.

So if you are in an environment with very little available memory and plan to have many connections, this information will help you to make optimal use of the little memory you have available for your program.

Comment: The passage is not referring to memory efficiency; it's referring to TCP data transfer efficiency.

Comment: The quote doesn't actualy say what your first sentence claims. It isn't the best piece of writing I've ever seen but it s talking about two cases at the same time: the case where it is rounded by 'some implementations', and the case where it isn't.